# Transformer removes the namespace incorrectly from xml

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, spring-ws

I have the following xml file which has namespace on NFe and enviNFe tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeAutorizacao4">
   <enviNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
      <idLote>203364605034338</idLote>
      <indSinc>0</indSinc>
      <NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
...
...
```

But while send the request, exactly on `WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult`, there is a Transformer that removes the namespace of the NFe tag, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeAutorizacao4">
   <enviNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
      <idLote>203364605034338</idLote>
      <indSinc>0</indSinc>
      <NFe>
...
...
```

The Webservice doesn't accept the request n this case.

What should I do to avoid this behavior?

Comment: `<NFe>` is already in that namespace, due to the `xmlns=` attribute of its parent.  The transformed XML is effectively the same.  If the web service doesn’t understand that, the web service is broken and does not conform to the XML specification.

Comment: @VGR Yes. I agree. But it's a government web service, so I need to find out a solution (workaround) at my side.

Comment: Interestingly, the inner `xmlns` attribute is only stripped when I transform to a StreamResult.  When I use a DOMResult, the attribute is retained.  I don’t know what can be done to fool the web service into accepting the XML, though.